# How to change string in setTitle for a generated text from outside class

Tags: python, pyqt, pyaudio

When I try updating a string variable in `self.graphWidget.setTitle(phrase, ...)` the variable doesn't update.
I'm plotting a real time waveform graph while recording from mic using *pyaudio* and *PyQT*, what I want to do is instead of printing in terminal I want the speech to text phrase to be shown in MainWindow after recognition is done

```
'''GUI'''
import struct
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
import sys

'''Graph'''
import pyqtgraph as pg
from PyQt5 import QtCore
import numpy as np

'''Audio Processing'''
import pyaudio
import wave
import speech_recognition as sr
import multiprocessing as mlti

FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 44100
CHUNK = 1024 * 2

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(
    format=FORMAT,
    channels=CHANNELS,
    rate=RATE,
    input=True,
    output=True,
    frames_per_buffer=CHUNK,
    )

frames = []
seconds = 6
phrase = "..."

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        pg.setConfigOptions(antialias=True)
        self.traces = dict()

        '''Display'''
        self.graphWidget =  pg.PlotWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.graphWidget)
        self.setWindowTitle("Waveform")
        self.setGeometry(55, 115, 970, 449)

        '''Data'''
        self.x = np.arange(0, 2 * CHUNK, 2)
        self.f = np.linspace(0, RATE // 2, CHUNK // 2)

        '''Animate'''
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.setInterval(50)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update)
        self.timer.start()  

    def set_plotdata(self, name, data_x, data_y):
        if name in self.traces:
            self.traces[name].setData(data_x, data_y)
        else:
            if name == 'waveform':
                self.traces[name] = self.graphWidget.plot(pen='c', width=3)
                self.graphWidget.setYRange(0, 255, padding=0)
                self.graphWidget.setXRange(0, 2 * CHUNK, padding=0.005)

    def update(self):

        self.wf_data = stream.read(CHUNK)
        self.wf_data = struct.unpack(str(2 * CHUNK) + 'B', self.wf_data)
        self.wf_data = np.array(self.wf_data, dtype='b')[::2] + 128
        self.set_plotdata(name='waveform', data_x=self.x, data_y=self.wf_data)

        self.graphWidget.setTitle(phrase, color="w", size="30pt")          #### Change it

def main():

        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        win = MainWindow()
        win.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())

def Record():
    for i in range(0, int(RATE/CHUNK*seconds)):
        data = stream.read(CHUNK)
        frames.append(data)
        print(i)

def Refine_Stream():
    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()
    p.terminate()

    obj = wave.open("output.wav", "wb")
    obj.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
    obj.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
    obj.setframerate(RATE)
    obj.writeframes(b"".join(frames))
    obj.close()

def Speech_Recog():

        print("Function Started")

        r = sr.Recognizer()

        #usando o microfone
        with sr.AudioFile("output.wav") as source:

            r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration=1)

            #Armazena o que foi dito numa variavel
            audio = r.listen(source)
            
            phrase = ""

            try:
            #Into recog
                phrase = r.recognize_google(audio,language='pt-BR')          #### To it
                print(phrase)

            #Couldn't make it
            except sr.UnknownValueError:
                phrase = "Not understood"
                print(phrase)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = mlti.Process(target=main)
    p1.start()


    Record()

    Refine_Stream()

    Speech_Recog()
```

Hope it was clean code enough

Comment: You cannot read the same stream from two different processes at the same time, and it wouldn't make any sense anyway, since they can perfectly work in the same process (so, *another* reason for not using multiprocessing for the wrong reason. Just use multithreading (I don't remember if pyaudio has an asynchronous API, but it should use a callback mechanism if I recall correctly).

Comment: In my case, after testing, it performs way better using multiprocessing instead of the usual multithread @musicamante

Comment: I'm not talking about the performance, but the usage of multiprocessing: what's the point of good performance if *it doesn't work*? You cannot access a global variable from a different process, because it's *not* the same variable. I've used threaded audio processing (including multiple file streams for both playing/recording) and has always performed quite fine even on my 10 year old PC, so it should work quite fine. In any case, the point remains: you cannot use mp like that, and if you *really* need mp, you should implement proper inter-process communication with appropriate data pickling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I studied quite a lot and I figured out how to do exactly what I wanted

I'm using a signal and slot system as `my_signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)` to send my string-variable as a signal to `setTitle` that is activated using `QTimer` after some time

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        '''Display'''
        self.graphWidget =  pg.PlotWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.graphWidget)
        self.setWindowTitle("Waveform")
        self.setGeometry(55, 115, 970, 449)
        self.graphWidget.setTitle(phrase, color="w", size="30pt")

        '''Animate Title'''
        self.picktimer = QTimer()
        self.picktimer.setInterval(7000)                        ###seconds needs to be more than seconds recording
        self.picktimer.timeout.connect(self.Transitioning)
        self.picktimer.start()

    def Transitioning(self):

        self.example_class = Speech_Recognition(self)

        self.example_class.my_signal.connect(self.Update_Title)
        self.example_class.Speech_Recog()                               ###init SpeechRecog

    def Update_Title(self, my_title_phrase):

        self.graphWidget.setTitle(my_title_phrase, color="w", size="30pt")
        QtWidgets.qApp.processEvents()

def main():

        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        win = MainWindow()
        win.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())

def Record():
    for i in range(0, int(RATE/CHUNK*seconds)):
        data = stream.read(CHUNK)
        frames.append(data)
        print(i)

def Refine_Stream():
    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()
    p.terminate()

    obj = wave.open("output.wav", "wb")
    obj.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
    obj.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
    obj.setframerate(RATE)
    obj.writeframes(b"".join(frames))
    obj.close()

class Speech_Recognition(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    my_signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def Speech_Recog(self):

            r = sr.Recognizer()

            recorded_phrase = ""

            #usando o microfone
            with sr.AudioFile("output.wav") as source:

                r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration=1)

                #Armazena o que foi dito numa variavel
                audio = r.listen(source)

                try:
                    recorded_phrase = r.recognize_google(audio,language='pt-BR')

                except sr.UnknownValueError:
                    recorded_phrase = "Not understood"

            self.my_signal.emit(recorded_phrase)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    p2 = mlti.Process(target=main)
    p2.start()

    Record()

    Refine_Stream()
```

Still needs to be clean code though